# conversion error - What is the find() return type?

Tags: c++, string, find

I'm trying to use find() to search a vector from start to finish and return the index of 'storage';

```
    int num = stoi(cap.substr(0, cap.find(' ')));
    string storage = (cap.substr(cap.find(' ' + 1)));
    vector<string> storageArr = { "A", "B", "AB", "BA", "AA" };
    int element = find(storageArr.begin(), storageArr.end(), storage);
```

'cap' would be a string, in the format of a number followed by a space followed by a string. (e.g: '128 B').
Once I split the original string, I want to search for the alpha sub-string in a vector (or array) and initialize the variable "element" to its location.

I was under the assumption that find() would return an unsigned int, but this doesn't seem to be the case, as I'm getting a "no suitable conversion error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the more pertinent question is, how could I convert the return type of find() to an int in order to perform arithmetic on it?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching (and trial and error), I came up with this:

```cpp
int index = find(storageArr.begin(), storageArr.end(), storage) - storageArr.begin();
```

This appears to convert the returned iterator to an int (the index where `storage` was found in `storageArr`).

Is there any predefined function that would do this for me?

Comment: Yes there is: `std::distance(first, last)`, which return the number of hops from first to last. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: @Nick `int index = distance(storageArr.begin(), find(storageArr.begin(), storageArr.end(), storage));`, which will end up returning an index of `storageArr.size()` if `storage` is not found.  But for a random-access iterator, like what `std::vector` uses, `std::distance()` will simply return `found - start`, like you already did.